# Quickfix session setting for Bloomberg

Tags: fix-protocol, quickfixj

I am trying to set up a connection with QuickFIX/J 2.1 towards Bloomberg for different sessions (EMSX, FIX, FX etc), but can't connect. I receive different error messages but mostly:

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Bloomberg have changed their handshake configuration from SSL to TLS recently. I am trying to log on with below settings:

```
[Default]
ConnectionType=initiator
LogonTimeout=30
ReconnectInterval=30
ResetOnLogon=N
SocketConnectPort=xxxx
SocketConnectHost=xx.xxx.xxx.xx
SenderCompID=MAP_xxxx_BETA

[SESSION]
#SettingsspecificallyforFXFI
BeginString=FIX.4.4
TargetCompID=MAP_xxx_BETA
HeartBtInt=60
DataDictionary=FIX44.xml
UseDataDictionary=Y
StartTime=09:00:00 Europe/Stockholm
EndTime=23:00:00 Europe/Stockholm
SocketKeyStore=D:BB\cert.jks
SocketKeyStorePassword=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
CheckLatency=N
MaxLatency=240
FileStorePath=messageslog\incoming
FileLogPath=messageslog\outgoing
EnabledProtocols=TLSv1.2
TargetSubID=BLOOMTest
ConnectionType=initiator
LogonTimeout=30
ReconnectInterval=30
ResetOnLogon=N
SocketConnectPort=xxxx
SocketConnectHost=xx.xxx.xxx.xx
SenderCompID=MAP_xxxx_BETA
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it establish a connection long enough to send a logon message?

Comment: Outgoing text message log are created. Outgoing text event log: Disconnecting: Socket exception (/IP): java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Comment: That's the event log, which is usually not very helpful.  Does it actually send a FIX logon message?

Comment: No, I dont think that a FIX logon message is sent to BB

Comment: What does the QuickFIX/J event log say? You can find it in FileLogPath, file is something like `<FIX version>-<SenderCompId>-<TargetCompId>.event.log`. [edit] your question and include the relevant bits. Also, you target/sender comp ID are suspiciously similar. Sure they're correct?

Comment: For what it's worth, you can review my settings file here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192375/show-rebecca-my-quickfix-j-config-file

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are missing the following setting in your `[SESSION]` configuration:

```
SocketUseSSL=Y
```

From the [configuration for QuickFIX/J docu](https://quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.3.0/usage/configuration.html):

> SocketUseSSL:     Enables SSL usage for QFJ acceptor or initiator.

By which they mean either SSL or TLS really, whichever you have enabled with the `EnabledProtocols` setting.

Comment: Thanks..Ive added the SocketUseSSL=Y, but still I get disconnected. According to BB it still looks like im connecting without a TLS certificate.

Comment: @Rebecca Are you sure you have this setting correct: `SocketKeyStore=D:BB\cert.jks`. To me that does not look like a valid path? I could be mistaken, but double check to be sure. Same with password.

Comment: In the SocketKeyStore, I refer to: Disk "D", folder BB, folder jks, and to the specific certificate named cert.jks. I have: SocketKeyStore= D:BB\jks\cert.jks

I also tried to change the back slash to /..but same outcome: Disconnected.

Have tried to find "path" samples, but they all look like mine above.

Comment: @Rebecca Have you tried `SocketKeyStore=D:\BB\jks\cert.jks` (with a backslash after the colon)?

Comment: Yes, I missed that in my text above, but I do state an backslash. When I removed it, I got an error message that cert not fount, so somehow it finds the certificate, but doesnt read it. Im using below settings: (adding a comment)

Answer (score 0):

From an example that works

```
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
ReconnectInterval=30
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
ResetOnLogon=Y
ResetOnLogout=Y
ResetOnDisconnect=Y
UseLocalTime=N
FileLogPath=Fix\QuickFixFiles\Bloomberg\Fxgo\xxxxxx\Logs
FileStorePath=Fix\QuickFixFiles\Bloomberg\Fxgo\xxxxx\Store

[SESSION]
BeginString=FIX.4.4
SenderCompID=xxxxxxxx
TargetCompID=xxxxxxxx
TargetLocationID=FXEM
SessionQualifier=Fxgo1
HeartBtInt=30
SocketConnectHost=xx.xx.xx.xx
SocketConnectPort=xxxx
DataDictionary=Fix\QuickFixFiles\Bloomberg\Fxgo\xxxxx\DataDictionary\MAP_v2.0_QuickFIX_FXGO.xml
SSLEnable=Y
SSLProtocols=Tls12
SSLValidateCertificates=N
SSLCertificate=Fix\QuickFixFiles\Bloomberg\Fxgo\xxxxx\TlsCerts\pkcs12\cert.pfx
SSLCertificatePassword=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```